# The type signature of Parsec function 'parse' and the class 'Stream'

Tags: haskell, types, parsec

What does the constraint `(Stream s Identity t)` mean in the following type declaration?

```
parse :: (Stream s Identity t)
  => Parsec s () a -> SourceName -> s -> Either ParseError a
```

What is `Stream` in the following class declaration, what does it mean. I'm totally lost.

```
class Monad m => Stream s m t | s -> t where
```

When I use Parsec, I get into a jam with the type-signatures (`xxx :: yyy`) all the time. I always skip the signatures, load the src into ghci, and then copy the type-signature back to my .hs file. It works, but I still don't understand what all these signatures are.

---

**EDIT: more about the point of my question.**

I'm still confused about the 'context' of type-signature:

```
(Show a) =>
```

means `a` must be a instance of class `Show`.

```
(Stream s Identity t) =>
```

what's the meaning of this 'context', since `t` never showed after the `=>`

---

I have a lot of different parser to run, so I write a warp function to run any of those parser with real files. but here comes the problem:

Here is my code, It cannot be loaded, how can I make it work?

```
module RunParse where
import System.IO
import Data.Functor.Identity (Identity)
import Text.Parsec.Prim (Parsec, parse, Stream)

--what should I write "runIOParse :: ..."
--runIOParse :: (Stream s Identity t, Show a) => Parsec s () a -> String -> IO ()
runIOParse pa filename =
  do
    inh <- openFile filename ReadMode
    outh <- openFile (filename ++ ".parseout") WriteMode
    instr <- hGetContents inh
    let result = show $ parse pa filename instr
    hPutStr outh result
    hClose inh
    hClose outh
```

Comment: Are you declaring types for your combinators? If not, maybe you get ambiguity errors?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> the constraint: (Stream s Identity t) means what?

It means that the input `s` your parser works on (i.e. `[Char]`) must be an instance of the `Stream` class. In the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.1/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#t:Stream) you see that `[Char]` is indeed an instance of Stream, since any list is.

The parameter `t` is the token type, which is normally `Char` and is *determinded* by `s`, as states the functional dependency `s -> t`.

But don't worry too much about this Stream typeclass. It's used only to have a unified interface for any Stream-like type, e.g. lists or ByteStrings.

> what is Stream

A Stream is simply a typeclass. It has the `uncons` function, which returns the head of the input and the tail in a tuple wrapped in `Maybe`. Normally you won't need this function. As far as I can see, it's only needed in the most basic parsers like `tokenPrimEx`.

**Edit:**

> what's the meaning of this 'context', since t never showed after the =>

Have a look at [functional dependencies](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies). The `t` never shows after the ´=>´, because it is determiend by `s`.
And it means that you can use `uncons` on whatever `s` is.

> Here is my code, It cannot be loaded, how can I make it work?

Simple: Add an import statement for `Text.Parsec.String`, which defines the missing instance for `Stream [tok] m tok`. The documentation could be a bit clearer here, because it looks as if this instance was defined in `Text.Parsec.Prim`.

Alternatively import the whole Parsec library (`import Text.Parsec`) - this is  how I always do it.

Comment: I feel that it is close to the answer, Can you explain more about the syntactic structure of `(Stream s Identity t)`? thanks a lot! P.S. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 11):

The `Stream` type class is an abstraction for list-like data structures.  Early versions of Parsec only worked for parsing lists of tokens (for example, `String` is a synonym for `[Char]`, so `Char` is the token type), which can be a very inefficient representation.  These days, most substantial input in Haskell is handled as `Text` or `ByteString` types, which are not lists, but can act a lot like them.

So, for example, you mention

```
parse :: (Stream s Identity t)
  => Parsec s () a -> SourceName -> s -> Either ParseError a
```

Some specializations of this type would be

```
parse1 :: Parsec String () a -> SourceName -> String -> Either ParseError a
parse2 :: Parsec Text () a -> SourceName -> Text -> Either ParseError a
parse3 :: Parsec ByteString () a -> SourceName -> ByteString -> Either ParseError a
```

or even, if you have a separate lexer with a token type `MyToken`:

```
parse4 :: Parsec [MyToken] () a -> SourceName -> [MyToken] -> Either ParseError a
```

Of these, only the first and last use actual lists for the input, but the middle two use other `Stream` instances that act enough like lists for Parsec to work with them.

You can even declare your own `Stream` instance, so if your input is in some other type that acts sort of list-like, you can write an instance, implement the `uncons` function, and Parsec will work with your type, as well.