# Missing instance errors, module loading and GHCi

Tags: haskell, import, ghci

it came from another question, but things has changed.

[The type signature of Parsec function 'parse' and the class 'Stream'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370094/the-type-signature-of-parsec-function-parse-and-the-class-stream)

I'm now wondering what does `import` do to make things different.

---

file:RunParse.hs

```
module RunParse where
import System.IO
import Data.Functor.Identity (Identity)
----import Text.Parsec ()     ....................(1)
----import Text.Parsec        ....................(2)
import Text.Parsec.Prim (Parsec, parse, Stream)

runIOParse :: (Show a) => Parsec String () a -> String -> IO ()
runIOParse pa fn =
  do
    inh <- openFile fn ReadMode
    outh <- openFile (fn ++ ".parseout") WriteMode
    instr <- hGetContents inh
    let result = case parse pa fn instr of
                   Right rs -> show rs
                   Left err -> "error"
    hPutStr outh result
    hClose inh
    hClose outh
```

---

(I'm using ghc 7.0.4)

load the file into ghci:

```
> :l RunParse.hs
```

it tells me:

---

```
RunParse.hs:13:23:
Could not deduce (Stream String Identity t0)
  arising from a use of `parse'
from the context (Show a)
  bound by the type signature for
             runIOParse :: Show a => Parsec String () a -> String -> IO ()
  at RunParse.hs:(8,1)-(18,15)
Possible fix:
  add (Stream String Identity t0) to the context of
    the type signature for
      runIOParse :: Show a => Parsec String () a -> String -> IO ()
  or add an instance declaration for (Stream String Identity t0)
In the expression: parse pa fn instr
In the expression:
  case parse pa fn instr of {
    Right rs -> show rs
    Left err -> "error" }
In an equation for `result':
    result
      = case parse pa fn instr of {
          Right rs -> show rs
          Left err -> "error" }
```

---

then I added either (1) or (2):

```
import Text.Parsec ()     ....................(1)
import Text.Parsec        ....................(2)
```

Then `:l RunParse` , load succeeded.

Then I remove all of (1) and (2), then `:l RunParse`, still succeeded!

Then I `:q` quit the ghci, restart ghci, just same as the start, it failed to load.

Does this is a bug of ghc, or I should know more about `import`?

P.S. RunParse.hs failed the `ghc -c --make RunParse.hs` without (1) and (2).

Comment: "Then I remove all of (1) and (2), then `:l RunParse`, still succeeded!" Regarding this part, when you loaded the file the first time and imported `Text.Parsec`, its functions remained in scope when you reloaded the modified file. Then when you quit and restarted `ghci`, you returned to the Prelude, where `Stream` is undeclared.

Comment: Have you read through http://learnyouahaskell.com/ ?  It covers a lot of this.

Comment: @Alex:I read it last year, But I forgot this. maybe because it not usually happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message tells you that the compiler can't find an instance declaration for `Stream String Identity t0`. This instance is defined in `Text.Parsec.String`:

```
instance (Monad m) => Stream [tok] m tok where
    uncons []     = return $ Nothing
    uncons (t:ts) = return $ Just (t,ts)
```

Importing `Text.Parsec` brings the `Stream` instance from `Text.Parsec.String` in scope and makes your code compile. Changing `import Text.Parsec()` to just `import Text.Parsec.String()` will also fix this error.

Your problem with code not loading after restarting GHCi is a [known issue](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/users_guide/bugs.html). GHCi doesn't do a very good job of controlling the scope of instance declarations. So after you have loaded a module once, instance declarations from it stay in scope for the rest of the session. That's why GHCi didn't complain after you removed the `import Text.Parsec ()` line.